# AngularJS bind objects with checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a nested list of object up to three level state. For each object there is a nested object itself up to n-level. I want to bind that object directly with the checkbox such that if I check any item It should get a direct impact on that particular object. IS there any way in angular to do that? A sample object is below.

Object which I am getting from the server side:

```
[{
    "name": "nvs_core",
    "discovered": [{
        "name": "tag",
        "Fields": [{
            "name": "tag",
       }]
    }]
    }]
}, {
    "name": "nvs_core_trial",
    "discovered": [{
        "name": "nvs_src_tag",
        "Fields": [{
            "name": "nid",
        }]
    }, 
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can attach model to your checkbox, if you want a different values for checked/unchecked you can see example here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D bottom page

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="myobj.discovered.Fields.name.checked" ng-repeat="myobj in ArrayOfObjects"/>
```